# Intermediate Value Theorem | iff or if?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, logic

I am a first-semester BSc. Engineering student and I have been studying the **Intermediate Value Theorem** as part of my coursework. I'm a bit confused about it's definition and would appreciate some clarification.

The Intermediate Value Theorem states that,

> ***'for a function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ which is continuous on a closed bounded interval;
>
> if $f(a) \not = f(b)$, $f(a)<u<f(b)$ or $f(a)>u>f(b)$ then there exists at least one $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c )= u$'***

Simply put, the theorem states that *if a function is continuous on a closed interval $[a, b]$, and there exists a value "c" between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then there must be at least one point "$u$" within $(a, b)$ where the function takes the value "$c$".*

I will leave a **proof** here for those who are interested,
[image]

However my confusion lies on the definition of the theorem.

**Can we ascertain whether the other way around is also true and therefore it's an *'if and only if'* case?**

That,

> ***'$iff$ function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous on a closed bounded interval then $f(a)<u<f(b)$ or $f(a)>u>f(b)$, $f(a) \not = f(b)$ and there exists at least one $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)= u$.'***

is true?

If so, how can we prove that?

Comment: Have you tried thinking of a counter-example? Can there be a function where $f(a) < f(c) < f(b)$ and $a < c < b$ which is not continuous?

Comment: $\tan(x)$ in the $[0,4]$ interval has a discontinuity at $\pi/2$

Comment: @Andrei $\tan x$ is not a function on $[0,4]$.

Comment: There is a theorem by Darboux which states that every derivative has this property, but of course there are plenty of differentiable functions that aren't of class $C^1$! See here for Darboux's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly not. For example, take $f\colon[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x&\text{if }x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
1-x&\text{if }x\notin\mathbb{Q}.
\end{array}\right.$$
This function is discontinuous at every point in its domain except $x=\frac{1}{2}$. But it takes every value strictly between $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ somewhere in $(0,1)$.

---

By the way, I would argue that a better "converse" would be phrased as follows (though it is of course false):

> Suppose that $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function such that for every $L$ strictly between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, there exists at least one $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=L$. Then $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

The property you want is sometimes called the "intermediate value property". A function $f\colon I\to\mathbb{R}$ (where $I$ is an interval) has the "intermediate value property" if and only if for every $a\lt b\in I$, if $L$ is a value strictly between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then there exists $c$, $a\lt c\lt b$, such that $f(c)=L$. But this is much weaker than continuity, as noted above.

Comment: Is there another example which is continuous at *no* point, yet for $a<b$ and $f(a) \neq f(b)$ takes on any values between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ at some $x \in (a,b)$?

Comment: @coffeemath: Yes; modify the values on the irrationals so it is a union of line segments that avoid the line $x=y$.

Comment: @coffemath: e.g., on $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, make it $1-x$ on $[0,\frac{1}{4}]$ and $x-\frac{1}{4}$ on $[\frac{1}{4},1]$.